# return from action from within a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller like this

```
MyController < ApplicationController

def my_method
  validate(params[:name].blank?, "Name can't be blank")
end
private

def validate(condition, msg)
  if condition
    flash[:notice] = msg
    redirect_to :back
    return
  end
end
```

This code, for obvious reasons, will have a "redirect or render only once" error. Is there an elegant way to return the action from within this method and avoid a test on my action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really force the caller of your method to do anything, but you can signal to it how you want it to behave:

```
def my_method
  return unless validate(params[:name].blank?, "Name can't be blank")
end

def validate(condition, msg)
  return true unless condition

  flash[:notice] = msg
  redirect_to :back
  return false
end
```

Comment: My hope is that I could find a method `stop_executing_action` or something within rails... Are you aware of something like that?

Comment: If your filter call returns `false` then execution will stop.